# CRYSTAL REPORTS ON VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report on my vb.net. I'm struggling on how to display database fields that is adjusting the space on the main report preview.

Is there a way to lessen the space automatically?? It will adjust how long the database field is.
I want the result to be like this

*" This Certify that Jose Arden Del Rosario of legal age are residents of "*

[The Main report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQDhZ.png)

[The result preview of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akJFb.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative solutions:

1. Create a text object and drag the database fields into it. This creates a composite object that concatenates the content.  Advantage: each component can maintain its own formatting. For example, you can easily make the name fields be bold and/or italics.
2. Create a formula that concatenates the pieces:

   "Some Text " + {fName} + " " + {lName) + " some more text"